# Issues with libgtk on upgrade to 18.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, xfce, gtk

I recently upgraded to 18.04 and various things are broken. In particular, various applications give error messages when trying to launch:

```
firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard

inkscape
inkscape: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: g_application_set_option_context_description

gimp
gimp: symbol lookup error: gimp: undefined symbol: g_object_new_with_properties

gedit
gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
```

Other things (Chrome, Sublime Text) work fine.

I'm using Xubuntu/xfce and it isn't working well either: none of the usual menu panels (whisker menu, power indicator, etc.) will work, and I can't login normally. On boot I get a loop between the usual startup screen and a black screen with a mouse, although I can switch to another tty and launch the GUI manually with startx.

It seems like some sort of graphics library didn't get upgraded properly, or maybe there's an old version hanging around. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that myself.

EDIT: I looked through /var/log/dist-upgrade/[upgrade date] and nothing looks odd, although I don't really know what to look for.

Comment: Were there any error messages when you upgraded? Old versions don't "hang around" if you installed them properly (using apt). Also check your upgrade logs in /var/log.

Comment: I didn't see any error messages when upgrading. I'm aware that apt should take care of this for me, but it seems to have not (and I've tried apt-get install --reinstall libgtk-3.0 and similar.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18, and practically no GUI or windowing is working.
Here is some information:

> $ gedit
>       gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0:
>    undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
>
> $ gnome-system-monitor
>    gnome-system-monitor: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1:
>    undefined symbol:
>   g_application_set_option_context_description
>
> $ dpkg -l gnome-shell
>   ii  gnome-shell    3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
>
> $ lsb_release -a
>   Distributor ID: Ubuntu; Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; Release: 18.04; Codename: bionic
>
> $ uname -a
>   Linux 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> $ dpkg -s libgtk-3-0
>   Version: 3.22.30-1ubuntu1
>   Provides: gtk3-binver-3.0.0

Comment: I fixed my problem by reinstalling. There might be a less intrusive fix but I doubt it's simpler.

Comment: @Calvin: can you re-install without damaging (overwriting or erasing) your data, directories and applications?